# Running Python directly is much faster compared to when Django runs python

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So I have a SQL query that takes really long to load using Django, 10000 rows takes about 30 seconds. If I run the exact same code directly using python it does this in 2 seconds. For some reason, the loop I built takes really long to execute when Django runs the code, does anyone know why that is? Can I do something to increase the performance and get rid of this inconvenience?

```
import psycopg2
def doQuery( conn ) :
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE substring(addr from 0 for 5) 
    = '\\x82332355'::bytea")


    return cur.fetchall()

myConnection = psycopg2.connect( host=hostname, user=username, 
password=password, dbname=database )
results = doQuery( myConnection )



def lists(t):
    if type(t) == list or type(t) == tuple:
        return [lists(i) for i in t]
    return t

results = lists(results)   

for result in results:
    result[1] = str(result[1]).encode("hex"))
    result[3] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(result[3])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    result[6] = "Not Avaliable"
    print result
```

This **for** loop  ^^^^^^^^ takes really long in Django, **fast in python**

```
myConnection.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean run in python exactly same code in django? Do you use django ORM? Do you use psycopg? How do you buld the query in both cases?

Comment: I use psycopg, the query takes about 1.5 seconds in both Django and when I run it through python directly. But then I have a loop that edits the query and gives me an edited list. Direct python does this really fast, but Django takes really long...

Comment: You really need to edit your post and put the code you've tried and explain your problem more preciselly. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok! Much better. But still don't understand want you mean by `run in django` or `run in python`. How do you do that? Do u copy that code to a django view? How are the two ways you run this code?

Comment: Run in Django means I have the code ran on the server, which means, I click on a button and the code runs. Run in Python means I run the file in command prompt directly from the directory.

Comment: 'I click on a button and the code runs'. How do you think that this whatever button you are clicking is connected to the file that this code is written? And which server are you talking about? How do you setup this thing?

Comment: I have the file print out the row number when it iterates over the list when it is editing it in the "for" loop, in the Django server shell and print out in Python shell. Python prints fast, Django much slower. I am just curious as to why Django is not printing with Python speed, but much slower. DEBUG is set to False.

Comment: It's like we are speaking different languages. I really re-read your post a few times and don't understand what you mean by run in django pressing a button in shell. Maybe is IDE you are using, definitelly is something I don't know. To me, running code in django is putting some code in a view or calling your script from a view. To query database is to wirte some code in a view using django ORM, like `Model.objects.all()`. I'll upvote your question and hope that someone else can understand what you want here. Welcome to stack overflow! ;)

Comment: I run the file using python command, i.e. python file.py in terminal. In Django I run the server python manage.py runserver in terminal. Then I go to the page that requests this search query search.html, it is coded in views.py to run  this code. Then I added print row number each time when iterated and set row = row + 1. in both the file.py and views.py script. Then I look at both terminals, the python one and django and see how fast each one is printing. Django is printing slow and python is printing fast. Both are timed, 2 seconds for file.py and 30 seconds for views.py.

Comment: So you are probing the 'for result in results loop'? That's not related to the query. Can you do the same with a list os the same size of the query result and check if you can remove psycopg2 from the problem?